# Is it possible to run tests via gradle directly from Windows cmd?

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, cmd

I've been running tests using the IntelliJ gradle user interface but now I need to run those tests directly from the Windows cmd. Is there a way to do that and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. There is a wrapper script that you can run with the appropriate command.

This runs your usual unit tests, that live in the "test" source set (i.e. `src\test`):

```
gradlew test
```

This runs all tasks of type test:

```
gradlew check
```